# How to prevent retrieval of all entries from bidirectional ManyToMany collection while adding new entry

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many, bidirectional-relation

I would like to know how to prevent retrieval of all entries from bidirectional ManyToMany collection while adding new entry into that collection.
I have User entity, that has bidirectional relationship with UserGroup entity.
When I add group in User entity it add User to group as well as the UserGroup is parent. The problem is that if I add a lot of groups (let say 20) to user, then user is being added to each group as well and all users (100+ per group) are retrieved from each group. It makes transaction to take a lot of time and shows significant lag while I only want to insert UserGroup into User's userGroups collection and have no need of selecting other users from those groups.

**User.java**

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
private Set<UserGroup> userGroups;

public void addGroup(UserGroup userGroup){
this.userGroups.add(userGroup);
userGroup.addUser(this);
}
```

**UserGroup.java**

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "group_users", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
private Set<User> users;

public void addUser(User user) {
   this.users.add(user);
}
```

**Method used**

```
@Transactional
public void addGroupsToUser(UserAddGroupsCommand userAddGroupsCommand, String username) {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    if (user != null) {
        List<UserGroup> userGroupList = userGroupRepository.findAllById(userAddGroupsCommand.getId());
        for (UserGroup userGroup : userGroupList) {
            user.addGroup(userGroup);
        }
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

So I can see in console, that all join table entries are selected for the group I am iterating at

**EDITED:** this is the code that execuded and I am not sure why.

```
select users0_.group_id as group_id1_0_0_, users0_.user_id as user_id2_0_0_, user1_.id as id1_7_1_ 
from group_users users0_ 
inner join User user1_ on users0_.user_id=user1_.id 
where users0_.group_id=?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try custom query  to gain better performance

`from UserGroup g left join fetch g.users where g.id in :IDS`

This way users in each group will be loaded in one query and not in N+1 queries.

Changing `@ManyToMany(FetchType.EAGER)` is not efficient, because users will be always loaded with UserGroup, also when not used.

Using `@EntityGraph` is same as `join fetch` query.

Comment: I just edited the last code snippet. I actually don't want this part to be executed after user gets added to group.

Comment: it will not execute for each group if you fetch users on the beginning when calling `userGroupRepository.findAllById`. Replace that with custom query   `from UserGroup g left join fetch g.users where g.id in :IDS`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to know which users are in a group (displaying it in application), then do unidirectional mapping. Remove `Set<User> users` from UserGroup class.

In User class use @JoinTable instead mappedBy:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "group_users", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id"))
private Set<UserGroup> userGroups;

public void addGroup(UserGroup userGroup){
    this.userGroups.add(userGroup);
}
```

Comment: Dear Peter. Actually I need. I have an option in front-end to add groups to user. And also I have option to access group and add users to group. So I guess bidirectional is needed.

Comment: You can always replace the reverse direction by a query method in a repository.